# Accessing Model from html

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this loop in my page that displays all the cities in my model. Lets say New York City is one of these cities and I just want to access New York City. How do I access a particular city instance from my model in Rails?

```
<% @cities.each do |city| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= city.name %></td>
        <td><%= city.country %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', city %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_city_path(city) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', city, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: can you write what do you exactly mean by 'access'?

Comment: I want to be able to do something like <td><%= link_to 'Show', NewYork %></td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an attribute of that object to access the object in the view:

For example, if the `name` attribute of your city was "New York City", then you would say:

```
City.find_by_name("New York City")
```

Of course, it's not super railsy to do this in the view, so just add this to to relevant controller action:

```
@newyork = City.find_by_name("New York City")
```

and use `@newyork` in your view.

Comment: and would i be able do something like <%= link_to 'Show', @newyork %>

Comment: So, the second argument to `link_to` has to be a path, so you'd do `<%= link_to 'Show', city_path(@newyork) %>`